# Define a pdf with a unique non-null value in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, probability

I'd like to define a pdf such as:

```
g(x):P(x=0)=1. and P(x!=0)=0.
```

i.e. a pdf where the only non-zero probability occurs when x=0. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiracDelta.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piecewise is a useful tool for these cases:

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x == 0}}, 0]
```

The above should do the job for you.

---

**Note:**

DiracDelta[0]=infinity ; which is obviously not equal to 1.